# iOS edit TextField of Uialertview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

Code:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name your Search" message:@"Save Search as" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] ;
                alertView.tag = 20;
                alertView.delegate = self;
                alertView.cancelButtonIndex = 1;
                alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
                [alertView show];

- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    if(alertView.tag == 20){
        UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        textField.text = @"testing";
        if ([textField.text length] == 0){
            return NO;
        }
    }
     return YES;  
}
```

I created a UIALERVIEW with TEXTINPUT mode.I did set textvalue in textbox.It does not allow me to edit textfield value when alertview appears.What is wrong with my code?thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'edit textfield value'? The keyboard doesn't pop out? Or the text field is not there at all? Do you get any error?

Comment: keyboard is popup.but i can not add or  delete textfield values

Answer (score 2):

Add this line :  `textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

After this line : `textField.text = @"testing";`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add UIAlertView's delegate method,

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
     NSString *test = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
}
```

and remove

```
textField.text = @"testing";
```

Comment: remove testing string from textfield.

Comment: textfield should have defaultvalue

Comment: u can set,
textField.placeholder = @"your text";

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name your Search" message:@"Save Search as" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil] ;
   alertView.tag = 20;
   alertView.delegate = self;
   alertView.cancelButtonIndex = 1;
      alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
   UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
   textField.text = @"testing";//set textfield text before showing alert
   [alertView show];



- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
 {
if(alertView.tag == 20)
   {
    UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    if (textField.text.length == 0)//it is correct way
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, make sure that you are conforming to the UITextField delegate within your view controller and within the view controller, set the UITextField's delegate to self.

Then, within the view controller, you can put in the methods that are required to respond to an edit request.

You should also make the alertView.textfield's delegate methods of shouldBeginEditing, didBeginEditing, didEndEditing, shouldEndEditing, shouldReturn and shouldChangeCharactersInRange are represented in your view controller.